# How to find specific value in a text file in python

Tags: python

> Good morning guys,
> my question is:
> I have a text file in this format:

```
1 00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,033 <font size="36">FrameCnt: 1, DiffTime:
33ms 2022-05-19 16:15:57,729,790 [iso : 110] [shutter : 1/640.0] [fnum
: 280] [ev : 0] [ct : 5284] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 240]
[dzoom_ratio: 20088, delta:10088],[latitude: 38.259025] [longtitude:
15.598678] [rel_alt: 9.737 abs_alt: 99.324] [Drone: Yaw:51.4,
Pitch:-1.8, Roll:-1.3] </font>

2 00:00:00,033 --> 00:00:00,066 <font size="36">FrameCnt: 2, DiffTime:
33ms 2022-05-19 16:15:57,762,098 [iso : 110] [shutter : 1/640.0] [fnum
: 280] [ev : 0] [ct : 5284] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 240]
[dzoom_ratio: 20088, delta:0],[latitude: 38.259030] [longtitude:
15.598689] [rel_alt: 9.737 abs_alt: 99.324] [Drone: Yaw:51.4,
Pitch:-1.8, Roll:-1.3] </font>
```

> My intention is to retrieve FrameCnt, latitude, and longitude values for block of 6 rows.
> That is my possible output:

```
1, 38.259025, 15.598678
    
2, 38.259030, 15.598689
```

> How is it possible to do this in python? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: In which format do you need the values?

Comment: Hi The_spider. In a dataframe format possibly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is always an empty row between those chunks of 6 rows, you can try something like this:

You can find the regex with explanation here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nzQBn0/1)

```
import re
import pandas as pd

with open('your_textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
chunks = data.split('\n\n')

out = []
for chunk in chunks:
    ls = re.findall(r".+?(?<=framecnt)\s?:\s?(\d+).+?(?<=latitude)\s?:\s?([\d+\.]+).+?(?<=longtitude)\s?:\s?([\d+\.]+)", chunk, flags=re.S | re.I)[0]
    out.append(ls)

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['Framecount', 'Latitude', 'Longtitude'],dtype=float)
print(df)

  Framecount   Latitude Longtitude
0          1  38.259025  15.598678
1          2  38.259030  15.598689
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good use for regex lookbehind. Lookbehind in regex is a regex part that needs to be before the match in order to be a valid match, but it isn't included in the return match. The syntax is `(?<=<lookbehind_regex>)`.

We are look here for the strings after "FrameCnt: ", "latitude: " and "longtitude: ", so our patterns will start with `(?<=FrameCnt: )` and so on.

Next, we want to find a digit, which can be floating point or not. This can be found using `[0-9.]+`. The `[0-9.]` part means any digit character or a period.  The `+` means that we want `[0-9.]` one or more times. This needs to be included in the match, so we place it outside the lookbehind.

Our pattterns will thus look like `(?<=FrameCnt: )[0-9.]+`, `(?<=latitude: )[0-9.]+` and `(?<=longtitude: )[0-9.]+`.

We could now hardcode these patterns with the three different words, but what if you decide tomorrow that you also need another value? That's why I would use a for loop and dynamically construct the pattern from a base pattern.

Here's the code:

```py
from regex import findall

pattern = "(?<=%s)[0-9.]+"
tofind = ["FrameCnt", "latitude", "longtitude"]
found = []

with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
    txt = file.read()

for string in tofind:
    newpattern = pattern % (string + ": ")
    found.append(findall(newpattern, txt))
print(found)
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2'], ['38.259025', '38.259030'], ['15.598678', '15.598689']]
```

Now we still have to change its data type into `int`, and put it into a `DataFrame`.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame as df

frame = df(found, dtype=float, index=tofind)
print(frame)
```

Output:

```
                    0          1
FrameCnt     1.000000   2.000000
latitude    38.259025  38.259030
longtitude  15.598678  15.598689
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by regex:

```
import re

regex = (r".*\[latitude: (.*)\] \[longtitude:\n"
    r"(.*)\] \[rel_alt.*")

test_str = ("1 00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,033 <font size=\"36\">FrameCnt: 1, DiffTime:\n"
    "33ms 2022-05-19 16:15:57,729,790 [iso : 110] [shutter : 1/640.0] [fnum\n"
    ": 280] [ev : 0] [ct : 5284] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 240]\n"
    "[dzoom_ratio: 20088, delta:10088],[latitude: 38.259025] [longtitude:\n"
    "15.598678] [rel_alt: 9.737 abs_alt: 99.324] [Drone: Yaw:51.4,\n"
    "Pitch:-1.8, Roll:-1.3] </font>\n\n"
    "2 00:00:00,033 --> 00:00:00,066 <font size=\"36\">FrameCnt: 2, DiffTime:\n"
    "33ms 2022-05-19 16:15:57,762,098 [iso : 110] [shutter : 1/640.0] [fnum\n"
    ": 280] [ev : 0] [ct : 5284] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 240]\n"
    "[dzoom_ratio: 20088, delta:0],[latitude: 38.259030] [longtitude:\n"
    "15.598689] [rel_alt: 9.737 abs_alt: 99.324] [Drone: Yaw:51.4,\n"
    "Pitch:-1.8, Roll:-1.3] </font>")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print(matchNum, end=" , ")
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print (match.group(groupNum), end=" ")
    print("")
```